# Fastest way to read long[] from file?

Tags: java, android, file, optimization, io

I have a file that contains about 200,000 long values that I want to read as fast as possible into a long[]. It's for an Android app; function calls are slow (so anything involving reading a long at a time with a "for" loop will be super slow) and I need loading to be fast. What can I use? Everything I look at seems to read only bytes fast.

I've used `ByteBuffer` and `FileChannel` from the NIO package before and this seems a really fast way to load arrays of values from files. However, I cannot work out how to use this to read  data into a long[]. I've tried wrapping a long[] as a LongBuffer, but I cannot see any way I can feed data from a file into a LongBuffer.

Edit: Whatever method I use, I need to be able to use `Arrays.binarySearch` on the `long[]` array at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure how these help. I can't see how they answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to *cast* a `byte[]` into a `long[]`. However, you could try to use a [`FileChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) to read the content into a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and then get hold of a [`LongBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/LongBuffer.html) through [`ByteBuffer.asLongBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asLongBuffer%28%29) from which you could get a `long[]` through [`LongBuffer.array()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/LongBuffer.html#array%28%29).

You could also try `FileChannel.map` to get a `MappedByteBuffer` of the file. This may be faster than going through a `FileChannel.read`.

If this doesn't work you could try to use a `FileChannel` to read the content into a `ByteBuffer` and then access the `long`s inside it, using `ByteBuffer.getLong(index)`.

---

An alternative solution. (No method-calls in the loop :-)

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[longCount * 8];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("lotsoflongs");
fis.read(byteArray);
fis.close();
for (int i = 0; i < longCount; i += 8)
    longArray[i >> 3] = ((long) byteArray[0+i]        << 56) +
                        ((long)(byteArray[1+i] & 255) << 48) +
                        ((long)(byteArray[2+i] & 255) << 40) +
                        ((long)(byteArray[3+i] & 255) << 32) +
                        ((long)(byteArray[4+i] & 255) << 24) +
                              ((byteArray[5+i] & 255) << 16) +
                              ((byteArray[6+i] & 255) <<  8) +
                              ((byteArray[7+i] & 255) <<  0);
```

I've benchmarked a few solutions now, and this one seems to be the fastest way of doing it. Also, note that the actual bytes read in `fis.read(byteArray)` may be less than the actual size of byteArray. Thus, if this should be done properly, you need to put it in a loop that iterates until all bytes have been read.

Comment: I need to be able to use the long[] like a long[] after though e.g. using it with Arrays.binarySearch

Comment: How about implementing a `List` of longs, backed by a byte-array, and use Collections.binarySearch?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? How would I create such a List object?

Comment: Like this: `class MyList implements java.util.List { byte[] backingArray; MyList(byte[] data) { backingArray = data; } /* all list methods you need */ }`

Comment: Hmm. Is there no easier way than having to implement a whole custom class? I'm confused why this is so hard to do in Java. :(

Comment: Updated my answer. Have you had a look at `ByteBuffer.asLongBuffer` ?

Comment: " ByteBuffer.asLongBuffer from which you could get a long[] through LongBuffer.array()", I've actually tried this but .array() will throw an exception. I think this is because there is no long[] to return when the wrapped array was byte[]

Comment: Ah, I see it too now. Updated the answer with an alternative solution. Try it out. It seems quite fast in my tests.

Comment: A couple points.  First, fis.read(byteArray) may return a short count and not read the entire array.  Second, don't the byteArray[n] accesses in the loop always extract the same (first) long - should they not be byteArray[i+n]?

Comment: That's faster than using DataInputStream's getLong() method? Mind to post your results with different methods you tested? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [DataInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html). Since you can easily find out the length of the file, you also know how many elements it contains (filesize / 8 byte).

```
 DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

 long count = filesize/8;
 long[] longArray = new long[count];

 for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
     longArray[i] = dataStream.getLong();
```

Guess that should be enough to give you an idea.

Comment: @aioobe: Why don't you just implement your own version of binarySearch for a LongBuffer? Should be fairly easy, and then you are done. :-)